# SUMIFs by only calculating unique values in another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I currently have a table with five columns:

```
A = Campaign
B = Person
C = Opportunity Name
D = Total Cost of Campaign
E = Date
```

I'm trying to use =sumifs to calculate the amount in column D only if: (1) it matches the exact value in cell H2 to column A, (2) the date range, in column E, is greater than the value in cell I2, and (3) it removes duplicates based on value in column C (so you can't sum if value appears more than once).

Please refer to my data table (also attached) as reference:

```
Campaign    Person  Opportunity Name    Total Cost of Campaign  Date
A           Bob     Airbnb              5000                   3/2/2017
B           Jim     Sony                10000                  3/2/2017
B           Jane    Coca-Cola           10000                  3/2/2017
C           Jim     Sony                200                    3/2/2017
B           Daniel  Sony                10000                  3/2/2017
B           April   Coca-Cola           10000                  3/5/2017
```

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`=SUM(
  UNIQUE(
   QUERY(A:E,"select C, D where A = '"&H2&"' and E > date '"&TEXT(H3,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")))`

Query will cut first two conditions. Unique will remove duplicates:

[image]